# Return system.time from evaluated function

Tags: r, evaluation

**R version 2.12, Windows XP**

I am attempting to write a function (say 'g') that takes one argument, a function (say 'f'), and returns the matched function. Furthermore, enclosed within the body of 'g' is a statement that tells the resulting object to return the value of system.time when the object is called.  An example will clarify.

What I want:

```
g <- function(f) {...}
z <- g(mean)
z(c(1, 4, 7))
```

with output

```
user system elapsed
0.04   0.00    0.04
```

What I have:

```
g <- function(f) {if (!exists("x")) {x <- match.fun(f)} else {system.time(x)}}
z <- g(mean)
z(c(1, 4, 7))
```

with output

```
[1] 4
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `!exists("x")` supposed to do? You don't have an argument called `x`?! Should it be `f` instead?

Comment: `!exists(x)` is supposed to check if I have already bound `f` to a symbol within the environment of `g`.

Comment: I hope this isn't for homework!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
g <- function(f){
  function(x){
    zz <- system.time(
        xx <- match.fun(f)(x)
    )
    list(value=xx, system.time=zz)
  }
}
```

In use:

```
g(mean)(c(1, 4, 7))

$value
[1] 4

$system.time
   user  system elapsed 
      0       0       0
```

---

You may want to think about how your return the values.  I used a list, but another option is to print the system time as a side effect and return the calculated value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  Can you elaborate on the expression `match.fun(f)(x)`? I was unaware that you could suffix an `match.fun(x)` expression.

Comment: `match.fun(f)` returns a function.  Call that `f`.  then `match.fun(f)(x)` simplifies to `f(x)`.  In other words, nothing special happens here.  Think about it: you create a function and pass it some arguments.

Comment: Ok. So you aren't required to supply argument(s), i.e. if you just wanted the function object then you could use `v <- match.fun(f)`. But if you want the output of the function, then use `match.fun(f)(x)`.

Comment: To elaborate on Andrie's comment, try these calls: `(function(a, b){a + b})`,  `(function(a, b){a + b})(5,5)`. That should help make sense of the results of `match.fun("mean")`, and `match.fun("mean")(1:100)`.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I made similar function for myself:

```
with_times <- function(f) {
    f <- match.fun(f)
    function(...) {
        .times <- system.time(res <- f(...))
        attr(res, "system.time") <- as.list(na.omit(.times))
        res
    }
}
```

For example:

```
g <- function(x,y) {r<-x+y; Sys.sleep(.5); r}
g(1, 1)
# [1] 2
g2 <- with_times(g) 
w <- g2(1, 1)
```

Timings can be extracted in two ways:

```
attributes(w)$system.time
# $user.self
# [1] 0
# $sys.self
# [1] 0
# $elapsed
# [1] 0.5
```

or

```
attr(w, "system.time")
# $user.self
# [1] 0
# $sys.self
# [1] 0
# $elapsed
# [1] 0.5
```